# Match the corresponding cell value for Variable1 to unordered Variable2-cell

Tags: sql-server

Experts, I need to match the value of a particular cell(in Variable1) to another cell(of Variable2) which placed in different Observation.

I'll share the example set to make it a clear picture.

```
ID D1   D2   D1x D2x
1  Med1 Med4 abc Null
2  Med2 Med5 def Null
3  Med3 Med3 ghi Null
4  Med4 Med6 jkl Null
5  Med5 Med1 mno Null
```

Here the D1 refers to Drug name, D1x refers Generic name. I updated the Dx1 value manually. All I need to update the matched values in all the consecutive variables.
Expected output: (using update query)

```
ID D1   D2   D1x D2x
1  Med1 Med4 abc jkl
2  Med2 Med5 def mno
3  Med3 Med3 ghi ghi
4  Med4 Med6 jkl Null
5  Med5 Med1 mno abc
```

Please suggest a code update query so that I can utilize in my dataset for further analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your update query like following using a self join.

```
UPDATE mt
SET d2x = s.d1x
FROM mytable mt
INNER JOIN mytable s ON s.d1 = mt.d2
```

**Note**: Replace `mytable`  with actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(ID INT, D1 NVARCHAR(200), D2 NVARCHAR(200), D1x NVARCHAR(200), D2x NVARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO @T (ID,D1,D2,D1x) VALUES
(1, 'Med1', 'Med4', 'abc'),
(2, 'Med2', 'Med5', 'def'),
(3, 'Med3', 'Med3', 'ghi'),
(4, 'Med4', 'Med6', 'jkl'),
(5, 'Med5', 'Med1', 'mno');

UPDATE t1
SET D2x = t2.D1x
OUTPUT 
  INSERTED.ID,
  INSERTED.D1,
  INSERTED.D2,
  INSERTED.D1x,
  INSERTED.D2x
FROM @T t1
LEFT JOIN @T t2
  ON t1.D2 = T2.D1
```